# How to compute the CDF of the ambulances travel time?

Tags: probability

**Question :** An ambulance travels back and forth at a constant specific speed $v$, along a road of length $l$. We may model the location of the ambulance at any moment in time to be uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,l)$. Also at any moment in time, an accident (not involving the ambulance itself) occurs at a point uniformly distributed distributed on the road; that is, the accidents distance from one of the fixed ends of the road is also uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,l)$. Assume the location of the accident and the location of the ambulance are independent. Suppose the ambulance is capable of immediate U turns, **compute the CDF of the ambulances travel time $T$ to the location of the accident**.

**My attempt :**

Let $X$ denote the location of the ambulance from a fixed point (say $A$) and let $Y$ be the location of the accident from the same fixed point. So the distance between the ambulance and accident location is $|X-Y|$. We need to find the CDF of $T=\dfrac{|X-Y|}{v}$.

We have that $F_T(t)=P(T\le t)$.

If $t<0$ then clearly $F_T(t)=0$. If $t\ge\dfrac{l}{v}$ then clearly $F_T(t)=1$.

For $0\le t<\dfrac{l}{v}$ we have $$F_T(t)=P\left(\dfrac{|X-Y|}{v}\le t\right)=P(Y-vt\le X\le Y+vt).$$
I am unsure what to do next. I know that $P(a\le X\le b)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$, but I am confused about whether I can use it here.

The answer in the book is $F_T(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0 &\text{if}& t<0\\ \frac{2v}{l}-\left(\frac{vt}{l}\right)^2&\text{if}&0\le t<\frac{l}{v}\\ 1&\text{if}&t\ge\frac{l}{v}\end{array}\right.$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute such probabilities, one typically uses the law of total probability. 
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y| \leq vt) = \int_{0}^{l} \mathbb{P}(|X-y| \leq vt \ | \ Y = y) F_Y(y)dy,$$
where $F_Y$ is the distribution function of $Y$. Note that the probability under the integral sign can be simplified since $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v.